# Remove the unnecessary spacing between elements inside an <ul>

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I have a small menu bar and three of of the elements inside the menu have further submenus. But the elements inside the menu bar have unnecessary spacing between them and also the submenus that I have created have an unnecessary background width which I have colored white in the code to make the reader understand. Because of this unnecessary width the hover effect that is supposed to appear on menu bar appears even if mouse is hovered on the invisible width  which is white in this case but on live code it wont be white. So since it wont be visible in live code visitors might be confused as to why the submenu is still not getting hidden even when they have removed their mouse away from the submenu. So I want to remove the unnecessary spacing between the elements and make their alignment right in the menu bar and also reduce the width of the submenu to width of links inside the submenu. I know this might be a bit difficult to explain so I am posting this fiddle link. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W5PsY/)

I cannot post the CSS code because only 30000 characters are allowed to be posted in a question so you can compile the code on your local machine by copying from jsfiddle. Sorry for that extra effort. Html also I am posting only because it is a necessity to post some code.

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="expertystemsHome2.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Expertystems</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="menu" id="tempMenu">
                <li class="Home"><a href="">AAAAAA</a></li>
                <li class="Repair"><a  href="">BBBBBB</a>  
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li>
                               <a  href="">b1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a  href="">b2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a  href="">b3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a  href="">b4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a  href="">b5</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a  href="">b6</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a  href="">b7</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a  href="">b8</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                </li>

                <li class="Unlock"><a id="tempUnlock" href="">CCCCCC</a>

                        <ul id="mozillaPain2" class="submenu2">
                            <li>
                                <a href="">c1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">c2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">c3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">c4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                </li>    
                 <li class="Expertise"><a id="Expertise" href="">DDDDDD</a>

                        <ul id="mozillaPain3" class="submenu4">
                            <li>
                                <a href="">d1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">d2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">d3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">d4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">d5</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">d6</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">d7</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">d8</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">d9</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">d10</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href=""><img style="width: 158px;height: auto;" src="images/creation.png"></a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>

                </li>
                <li class="Careers"><a  href="">EEEEEE</a></li>
                <li class="Contact"><a  href="">FFFFFF</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>




    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using a tool to generate your code you should include it in your question.  It may help you get some better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a tool to generate this code?  If so it doesn't appear to be working.

**Here is a summary of what is happening:**

If you take a closer look and inspect the elements that have all of the spacing.  The elements themselves have these really large `margin-left:x;`

```
    ul.menu .Unlock a {
    margin-left: 185px;
    ....

    ul.menu .Expertise a {
    margin-left: 277px;
    ....
```

If you manually go through and remove all of these margins your menu will start coming together.

But I would take a closer look at the tool you may be using because that is really were your problem is.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5PsY/3/)

Comment: Oops, that was so silly, it completely removed the space. Thanks. Now the only problem I have is the width of the submenu background.. (white in color) in the jsfiddle I posted. Appreciate the help thanks.

Comment: Did you hand type all of this code, or is it being generated by something?

Comment: it is completely hand written, anyways the white background got removed by removing the margin from the submenu li a{margin:auto} elements. Now only their alignment is the problem they dont appear exactly below the button they are supposed to. Check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/W5PsY/7/

Comment: Where you have `top:46;` you need to update it to `top:33;` or some other number to bring it closer to your menu

Comment: Its not the top, but the left that is bothering me.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `margin-left`?  You can even make it a negative number if need be?

Comment: Then I'll have to change it for all browsers , But yeah I had tried that in the past.

Comment: Anyways I guess Ill have to take this step. But you were quite helpful. Thank you. Marked as an answer and Upvoted. Thank you.

Comment: @kapilchhattani to adjust left clear all margins and paddings than add position absolute to your ul like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/W5PsY/12/

Answer (score 2):

try adding `style="margin: 0;"` to the ul-element or add `ul { margin: 0; }` to your stylesheet

Comment: nope indeed, but your code is a real mess, try cleaning it up ;)

Comment: Haha.. You wont believe this is the cleaner version. The one before this had so many unnecessary lines of code that nobody was even ready to read.. But still I am trying.

Comment: I'm more than willing to help you, but searching through over 700 lines of CSS is a bit much

Comment: I appreciate and totally understand that. But you can use this fiddle and just make this one submenu appear correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/W5PsY/8/

Comment: first of all remove `background-color: white;` from `ul.menu .submenu`, this removes the white background of the submenu

Comment: No the width of the background was exceeding the width of the menu so I had introduced the white backgorund to make it clear to the people of this forum. But I dont know why in jsfiddle the background width is proper.

Comment: try this, that's the best I can do at the moment, I'd appreciate a vote :) http://jsfiddle.net/W5PsY/14/

Comment: Oops I am so sorry. I shud already upvoted. But now did. on answer as well as comments. Thank you.